# Why does the same RAM chip benchmark 2x faster on Intel CPUs?

Tags: memory, performance, cpu

Compare memorybenchmark.net's benchmarks for the "Kingston KHX2133C11D3/4GX 4GB" chip in the [read uncached ddr3 intel](http://www.memorybenchmark.net/read_uncached_ddr3_intel.html) vs [read uncached ddr amd](http://www.memorybenchmark.net/read_uncached_ddr3_amd.html) benchmarks.

The Intel speed is listed at 14,881 MB/s , while the AMD speed is listed at 7,042 MB/s . Across the board, the Intel speeds are way faster. Why is there such a drastic difference? Is it an artifact of the way the benchmark was done, or does it represent a huge advantage for Intel CPUs?

Comment: You'll have to ask Intell and AMD....

Comment: @mdpc Why can't he ask here? I'd like to know why too.

Comment: nice but the vendors will have the definitive information....about all that could be added would be opinion and conjecture.

Comment: @mdpc I mean, it's I'm guessing that Intel and AMD have different memory controller architectures, because according to the benchmarks Intel chips can utilize the bandwidth offered by DDR3 while AMD chips simply don't, but it's not going to be some secret. I just never read about AMD chips. It's not a bad question: What's different about them?

Comment: Without information about the benchmark (other than "uncached reads") or the systems tested (other than processor vendor and memory module), how can one draw any conclusions? The explanation could be as simple as the Intel systems having four memory channels and the AMD systems having two. Perhaps the AMD system is using an in-CPU GPU with the GPU taking some of the memory bandwidth? Without details one can only guess.